# email queue qmail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, queue

Is there any way for me to check the mail queue on an ubuntu server using qmail without SSH access.

If not are there any free email stats programs that would do a similar job that you can recommend.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot check these stats without shell access.

If you want to make it available for example via WWW, you can use **[RRDtool](http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/)** to collect data and generate graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have already installed it( From the sitehttp://www.webmin.com/rpm.html) then you can use Webmin. Just log in to Webmin then go to servers and click on Qmail server and you will see all the information including queue size. You can then login to see the queue. In general managing Qmail is best done via the command line. Hope this helps.